# Can you anyone help me with steps to find area between two graphs?

Tags: calculus

I am trying to find the area between
y = $9x$ and  y = $x\sqrt{17^2 - x^2} $

is someone can help me with steps it will be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: What steps are you tried? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: Begin by finding where these curves intersect. That will give you the limits of integration.

Comment: I gets intersections are x = $\sqrt{208}$ and total area in negative number.

Comment: Graph it out on a graphing calculator or perhaps you have a computer program that can do it. It will look more intuitive when you do that.

Comment: @user60878 : As you have doubtless noticed, we cannot answer your real question unless you explain what you have tried. Please edit the question and add more details so that we can help you through those parts of the problem where you are actually stuck.

Comment: There may be more than one interpretation. I would find the first quadrant area and multiply by $2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You calculated the point of intersection correctly (the other is at zero). Here's a graph:

[image]

I'm guessing that you only care about the values where $x \geq 0$, so your integral should look like:

$$\int_{0}^{\sqrt{208}}x\sqrt{17^2 - x^2} - 9x\,\mathrm dx$$
If you are getting a negative answer, I'm guessing you have the integrands transposed.